# Mathematical operations in pipeline

Tags: powershell

I use following code to get chrome total memory usage in megabytes

```
$usage = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "chrome"} | Measure-Object -Sum -Property PrivateMemorySize
"Total: " + $usage.Sum / 1e+6;
```

How can I do same thing in one line? I've figured out how to access properties in pipeline, but I don't know how to divide it by 1e+6.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "chrome"} | Measure-Object -Sum -Property PrivateMemorySize | select Sum
```

Comment: `(everything-and-the-pipeline-and-the-kitchen-sink).Sum / 1e+6`.

Comment: Or using a calculated property `(...| Select @{Name='Total';Expression={$_.Sum / 1e6}}).Total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution that uses true [*binary* MB units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (*mebibytes*, `[math]::Pow(2, 10*2)`, `1,048,576` bytes) rather than *decimal* ones (`[math]::Pow(10,6)` / `1e6`, `1,000,000` bytes)

```
"Total: $(((Get-Process 'chrome').PrivateMemorySize | measure -Sum).Sum / 1mb)"
```

(Replace `1mb` with `1e6` if you really want to use *decimal* units.
Note, though, that in terms of *RAM* - as opposed to *mass storage* - [*binary* units are still prevalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards))

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly what you asked for, use:

```
((Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'chrome'} | Measure-Object -Sum -Property PrivateMemorySize|% {$_.Sum}) /1e+6)|% {"Total: $_"}
```

Answer (score 2):

just simply like this :)

```
"Total: {0} " -f ((gps -Name "chrome" | Measure -Sum PrivateMemorySize).Sum/ 1e+6);
```